# divding numbers from 1 to 100 into sets

Tags: combinatorics

if sets are created using this rule $a  \times 2^m$ where $a$ is an odd number e.g

$a=1   {1,2,4,8,16,32,64}$

$a=3   {3,6,12,24,48,96}$

$a=99  {99}$

hence there are $50$ such sets. Will every number from $1-100$ inclusive appear in exactly one of these sets? If so why?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the $n$th odd number, it'll certainly appear in the $n$th set.

If it's the $n$th even number, you can divide by 2 until you get an odd number; it'll appear in that odd number's set.

Answer (score 1):

The prime factorization theorem says that every natural number can be written uniquely as a product of primes. Applying this to $N = 2^{l} 3^{m} 5^{n} …$, we can group all of the powers of odd primes into a single odd factor and we get $N = 2^l \times O$ where $O$ is odd. So every natural can be written uniquely in that form. And if you carry this out for all $N$'s which are $\le 100$ then all of the odd numbers $\le 100$ will occur as the odd factors amongst those $N$, fifty of those odd numbers in all.

Comment: how do you know that all of the odd numbers will occur as the odd factors amongst the N?

Comment: @zebra1729: $77$ is an odd factor of $77$, for example.